# Task Scheduler cant run an application

Tags: task, scheduled-tasks

i define a task to run a program in a certain time, but it appears an errors once it runs.
[image]

first one

[image]

second one

i tried to reinstall the kernell dll but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd screenshot has the error.  The constructor for "frmPDF" tries to read a file, but the file could not be found.

Figure out which file it is trying to load and see if it really exists.  If it does exist, then the "working directory" property of the scheduled task might need to be changed so it can be found.

Comment: where is located that property?

Comment: my frm reads 3 txt path files,i've to add those txt in the directory of tasks?